# Error : Login Profile for User XXXXXX cannot be modified while login profile is being created. (EntityTemporarilyUnmodifiable)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I have created an IAM User with login profile (Password) using Python SDK (Boto3). The user creation was success.

When trying to delete the Login Profile of the IAM User, I'm getting the below error :

> An error occurred (EntityTemporarilyUnmodifiable) when calling the
> DeleteLoginProfile operation: Login Profile for User XXXXXX cannot be
> modified while login profile is being created.

After i wait for few minutes and then run the code again, the code works.

This issue started from few days ago and now it has became a frequent error.

Any problems with IAM ?

Comment: How long do you wait before delete?

Comment: more than a min, I dont think its wait issue. This issue started few days ago. This is random too.

Comment: Seems like an AWS issue : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=74890